# Cannot backspace across wrapped lines in terminal

Tags: terminal, readline, word-wrap

Suppose your terminal window is 80 columns wide and you run a python script containing only:

```
print("x" * 81 + "\b\by")
```

You would expect the output to be a line full of `x` except for the last one, which should be a `y`. My problem is the output I get is a line full of `x` and a second line containing a lonely `y`. The fact is that whenever the backspace character is to be printed to stdout, it works as expected except when there are wrapped lines and it should place the cursor one line above: in that case it seems to be excluded from the stdout buffer.

I can reproduce this behaviour in a number of ways along the lines of the snippet above, e.g. `echo -e "xx...x\b\by"` tried with bash and sh, `printf(...);` for C/C++, `cout << ...;` for C++. The same issue when `cat` a file which contains backspace characters and also when typing for a stdin read which takes more than one terminal-window-line. In the latter case, `'\b'` characters are subsituted by me hitting the backspace key multiple times: when I exceed the window width and lines wrap, I cannot reach previous lines by repeatedly hit backspace, but those hits are processed as expected by the calling program, e.g. in a `scanf("%s", s);` call, `s` would then contain 79 `x` and 1 `y`, following the example above. The funny thing here is that if I resize the window such that the new cursor position is not at the first column of the window anymore, then I'm able to backspace back to the new first column place and go ahead this way untill only one terminal-line is left; then it turns out there is a position I cannot backspace further - but I could not figure out how to predict that position.

Finally, another situation when wrapped lines and backspace meet is when typing a long command and willing to backspace back to the first line. I face no problems in doing that.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and tried all the above with various terminal emulators, namely gnome-terminal, xvt and tilda. Any hint would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the result of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmux`, `screen`, `urxvt` behave the way you wish. `xterm` can be switched to that behavior by enabling [reverse-wraparound mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_): `printf '\e[?45h'`.

It's legacy, indeed broken by design, and no one really cared to fix it. There are more issues than the one you pointed out. See [VTE issue 62](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/issues/62) for further details.

> when typing a long command and willing to backspace back to the first line. I face no problems in doing that.

In this case you're using the shell's line editing (e.g. the readline library) which does more complex screen handling than just emitting a backspace.

Comment: Thank you! So, just to be sure, if I need reverse-wraparound I have to leave gnome-terminal aside, right? Its man page says it emulates xterm, but trying that same control sequence seems to have no effect with it.

Comment: "if I need reverse-wraparound I have to leave gnome-terminal aside, right?" – yes, although I'd rather suggest to write portable apps which e.g. compute how many lines the output occupies (comparing the string's width against the terminal's) and move the cursor upwards accordingly, or such.

Comment: "Its man page says it emulates xterm" – gnome-terminal doesn't have an official man page. Some 3rd party vendors add a short one. In many aspects gnome-terminal tries to emulate xterm, but xterm has many more rarely used features that are missing. It's practically impossible to duplicate all of xterm's features (and bugs), if you really need them, use xterm :P

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Python 3.7.4

```
print("x" * 81 + "y")


xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy
```

Is that what you want?